# Why is time complexity O(n!) not O(n * n!)

Tags: python, algorithm, permutation

Here's a [link to a youtube video @ 11:50](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KukNnoN-SoY&t=705s) which shows the following recursive tree:

[image: screenshot of recursive tree shown in video]

The code would be something like:

```py
class Solution:
    def permute(self, nums: List[int]) -> List[List[int]]:
        res = []
        
        def helper(curr: List[int], remains: List[int], res: List[List[int]]):
            if not remains:
                res.append(curr)
                return
            
            for i in range(len(remains)):
                next_num = remains[i]
                helper(curr + [next_num], [num for num in remains if num != next_num], res)
                
        helper([], nums, res)
        return
```

The video said there is *O*(n!) function call, however it seems to be a bit more so may be this is roughly, however in every step we have to copy over at worst n elements for new remaining array, so why does that not become *O*(n * n!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an `n`-argument list, `helper` makes `n` recursive calls on a list with `n-1` elements. That means its runtime is T(n) = n*T(n-1). Solving for T yields `n!`, something that's obvious if you unroll it a few rounds yourself:

```
T(n) = n * T(n-1)
     = n * (n-1) * T(n-2)
     = n * (n-1) * (n-2) * T(n-3)
     = ...
     = n! * T(0)
```

It would be O(n*n) if it made *one* recursive call on a list of `n-1` elements.

Comment: So we dont care about the time it takes to copy over a new array on each call?

Comment: We do and we don't. (Sorry, I misread `O(n*n!)` and `O(n*n)`.) The equation should be `T(n) = n*T(n-1) + O(n^2)`, which.. maybe does work out to `O(n*n!)`?  However, there's not much practical difference between O(n!) and O(n\*n!); both are exponential and so very slow. That said, one could get rid of the factor of `n` by using a different data structure that would let you remove a given value in O(1) time rather than having to rebuild the set with every element *but* the given value.